# How to add placeholder for v-input-field in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
 <input class="otp-number-login" 
                         input-classes="otp-number-login" type="password" placeholder="-" />
                        <input class="otp-number-login" 
                        input-classes="otp-number-login"  type="password" placeholder="-" />
                        <input class="otp-number-login"
                         input-classes="otp-number-login"  type="password" placeholder="-" />
                        <input class="otp-number-login"
                         input-classes="otp-number-login" type="password" placeholder="-" />
```

```html
<v-otp-input
                              ref="otpInput"
                              input-classes="otp-number-login"
                              separator=""
                              :num-inputs="4"
                              :should-auto-focus="true"
                              :is-input-num="true"
                              input-type="password"
                              @on-change="handleOnChange"
                              @on-complete="handleOnComplete"
                            />
```

Reference from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input

I am having otp input field, So in the middle of each input field, I want place "-".

("-" is prefilled in otp field,before entering otp )

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to select the component's `input`s, and set the `placeholder`:

```js
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    this.setInputPlaceholder()
  },
  updated() {
    // also apply placeholder in `updated()` in case component gets re-rendered
    this.setInputPlaceholder()
  },
  methods: {
    setInputPlaceholder() {
      this.$refs.otpInput.$el
        .querySelectorAll('input')
        .forEach(input => input.placeholder = '-')
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-input-placeholder-in-vue-otp-input-2shfx?file=/src/App.vue:581-695)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. After replacing the above code, i am getting error as 

(error  Assignment to property of function parameter 'input'  no-param-reassign)

Comment: In order to clear the error i have placed  in the method "/*eslint no-param-reassign: "error"*/"

Now the issue is, At the beginning, placeholder is not showing(Only showing placeholder if i enter any digit, then only its reflecting)

Comment: That doesn't occur in the demo. Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: Yes in the demo, it's working fine, but in my local when adding above code, In console i am getting as(((((( "TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined"

Comment: I am thinking because of this, initially placeholder is not reflecting. Can you please check if anything to be added

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

This option has not been supported by the creator yet.

There is an issue on the git repo open since March 2:
https://github.com/bachdgvn/vue-otp-input/issues/41

Comment: Any other alternative ways, For placing the placeholder.(With css?)

Comment: I recommend that you create your own input or fork this input to do it on your own.